# How can this function be written without cases?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

The function,

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  (e^x-1)/x  & x\neq 0 \\
  1 & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$

is continuous and differentiable at $x=0$. By composition, the $x\neq 0$ case is analytic everywhere it is defined, and integrating $f$ around $0$ in the complex plane yields $0$ and suggests that there is no pole there. Furthermore, working from the Taylor series of $e^x$, the $x\neq 0$ case can be seen to have a series that is defined at $0$ and equal to $1$:

$$
\frac{e^x - 1}x = \frac{-1 +\sum^\infty_{k=0} x^k/k!}{x} = \frac{\sum^\infty_{k=1} x^k/k!}{x} = \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{1} {k+1}\frac{x^{k}} {k!}
$$
From this we can also see that $f$ is analytic and infinitely differentiable.

All taken together, it seems strange that such a nicely behaved function would have an irremovable "patch" necessary at $x=0$. Nonetheless, I have not been able to come up with another way to write the function that allows it to be defined at zero without a special case there. Is it impossible to write this analytic function without a case block?

Comment: You mean without an infinite summation either as well?

Comment: Would you accept $\lim_{\xi\to x} (e^\xi - 1)  / \xi$?

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer this question without knowing what qualifies as a good representation of the function. @Y.D.X. 's suggestion seems as reasonable as any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question lies within your derivation of the Maclaurin series expansion of $f.$ You made a mistake in simplification. You wrote that $$\frac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{(k+1)!},$$ but this is not entirely correct. The simplification $$\frac1{x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{k-1}}{k!}$$ is only valid for $x\neq0.$ Nonetheless, because the function is piecewise defined, it just so happens that the Maclaurin series expansion also works at $x=0,$ but that is not due to your derivation; rather, that is due to the patching itself done piecewise.

Now, as you indicate, this does indeed demonstrate that $f$ is continuous and differentiable at $0.$ In fact, it is real-analytic at $0,$ and furthermore, it extends to an entire function. So $0$ is merely a removable singularity of the function $g$ defined by $$g(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}.$$ What this means is that $$\lim_{t\to0}g(t)=1=f(0).$$ Since $g$ is continuous everywhere else, it follows that $$g(x)=\lim_{t\to{x}}g(t)=f(x).$$ So we can simply define $$f(x)=\lim_{t\to{x}}g(t)=\lim_{t\to{x}}\frac{e^t-1}{t}.$$ This is a form of representing $f$ without using cases.